# Ubuntu Can't Locate Git Repositories After Upgrade

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

After I upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 14.10 (now up to 15.04), I lost the ability to connect to GitHub and Bitbucket using git protocol, https and ssh work fine:

`ssh -T git@github.com
Hi Arbolista! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Awesome.

`git remote add github git@github.com:arbolista/my_repo.git
git remote -v
github  https://github.arbolista/my_repo.git (fetch)
github  https://github.arbolista/my_repo.git (push)
git pull github master
fatal: repository 'https://github.arbolista/my_repo.git/' not found`

Not so awesome and driving me nuts. I've reinstalled git (now on the latest 2.5.2) and my ssh keys to no avail - I'm completely lost on this.

I've also made sure the git port is not firewalled:

`sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive`

My ~/.ssh/config looks like this (unchanged from when it was working):

`Host github.com-arbolista
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: As is kind of obvious from the output, it's actually the https access that is failing.

Answer (score 2):

Open `.git/config`. There should be a section named `[remote "github"]` with `url=https://github.arbolista/my_repo.git`

Change the `url` to `git@github.com:arbolista/my_repo.git`

Comment: Thanks, for the insight. The problem was with my [~/.gitconfig](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) file. Not sure why this would have changed during the upgrade. Somehow `[url "https://"] insteadOf = git://` got added, which would explain the output from `git remote -v` showing "https" instead of "git" right after I added the "git" remote. Https connection was fine, but that configuration was obviously confusing git when connecting.

Comment: @EricH. Git will only do what you tell it to do. So, no it wasn't confused. You can clearly see it in the output you posted. `github` remote is already defined with the url `https://github.arbolista/my_repo.git`, which of course is not valid github URL.

Comment: Haha, I'm not blaming git - my settings were invalid. I just don't know how that setting got there - either some over reach in the Ubuntu upgrade, or something I did unintentionally just before the upgrade.